# Is there a better way to retrieve the elements of a delimited pair in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have entries of the form: `cat:rat` and I would like to assign them to separate variables in bash. I am currently able to do this via:

```
A=$(echo $PAIR | tr ':' '\n' | head -n1)
B=$(echo $PAIR | tr ':' '\n' | tail -n1)
```

after which `$A` and `$B` are, respectively, cat and rat. echo, the two pipes and all feels a bit like overkill am I missing a much simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) command

```
entry=cat:rat
IFS=: read A B <<< "$entry"
echo $A    # => cat
echo $B    # => rat
```

Comment: +1, but maybe add some extra parameters (ie, `IFS=: read -r A B <<< "$entry"` to handle more cases? (not necessary with that value of entry, though...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes using [bash parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
PAIR='cat:rat'
A=${PAIR/:*/}
B=${PAIR/*:/}
echo $A
cat
echo $B
rat
```

Alternately, if you are willing to use an array in place of individual variables:

```
IFS=: read -r -a ARR <<<"${PAIR}"
echo ${ARR[0]}
cat
echo ${ARR[1]}
rat
```

EDIT: Refer glenn jackman's answer for the most elegant `read`-based solution

Comment: An alternative to the `${var/:*/}` syntax would be `${var#:*}` and `${var%*:}`. It's not necessarily better, but has been around longer, so might work better if you run across an ancient version of `bash` somewhere (also works on `ksh` and `zsh`).

Answer (score 0):

```
animal="cat:rat"
A=echo ${animal} | cut -d ":" -f1
B=echo ${animal} | cut -d ":" -f2
```

might not be the best solution. Just giving you a possible solution